# How spacy matcher works?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am trying to create a dataset for trainin using Spacy matcher, so I am using the matcher explorer but i dont understand exactly how it works.

URL: [url-matcher](https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher?text=New%20information%20about%20how%20the%20Conti%20ransomware%20group%20compromised%20the%20Costa%20Rica%20government%20has%20come%20to%20light%2C%20demonstrating%20the%20attack%E2%80%99s%20accuracy%20and%20how%20fast%20it%20moved%20from%20initial%20access%20to%20the%20final%20phase%20of%20encrypting%20machines.%0A%0AThe%20Conti%20ransomware%20organization%20only%20launched%20one%20more%20attack%20(Costa%20Rica)%20before%20switching%20to%20a%20different%20organizational%20structure%20that%20depends%20on%20numerous%20cells%20cooperating%20with%20other%20gangs.%0A%0ALet%E2%80%99s%20Dig%20Deeper%20into%20the%20Attack%20on%20the%20Costa%20Rica%20Government%0AThe%20Conti%20ransomware%20operation%2C%20which%20was%20initiated%20in%202020%20to%20take%20the%20place%20of%20Ryuk%2C%20quickly%20gained%20notoriety%20after%20attacking%20targets%20in%20both%20the%20private%20and%20public%20sectors%2C%20including%20American%20local%20governments%2C%20educational%20institutions%2C%20and%20national%20healthcare%20systems.%20The%20highly%20destructive%20ransomware%20is%20believed%20to%20be%20the%20work%20of%20a%20Russia-based%20cybercriminal%20organization%20that%20goes%20by%20the%20alias%20Wizard%20Spider.%0A%0AOn%20April%2011%2C%202022%2C%20the%20gang%20launched%20their%20final%20attack%20under%20the%20Conti%20name%20after%20obtaining%20initial%20access%20to%20the%20network%20of%20the%20Costa%20Rican%20government%20and%20conducting%20reconnaissance%20activity.%0A%0AThe%20steps%20taken%20by%20the%20Russia-based%20cybercrime%20group%2C%20from%20gaining%20initial%20access%20to%20stealing%20672GB%20of%20data%20on%20April%2015%20and%20deploying%20the%20ransomware%2C%20are%20explained%20in%20a%20report%20published%20by%20cyber%20intelligence%20company%20Advanced%20Intelligence%20(AdvIntel).%0A%0AAccording%20to%20BleepingComputer%2C%20the%20attacker%20entry%20point%20was%20a%20system%20belonging%20to%20Costa%20Rica%E2%80%99s%20Ministry%20of%20Finance%2C%20to%20which%20a%20group%20member%20called%20%E2%80%98MemberX%E2%80%99%20managed%20to%20obtain%20access%20over%20a%20VPN%20connection%20utilizing%20hacked%20login%20information.%0A%0AAdvanced%20Intelligence%20CEO%20Vitali%20Kremez%20claims%20that%20the%20impacted%20credentials%20were%20collected%20due%20to%20the%20malware%20that%20has%20been%20deployed%20on%20the%20initial%20machine%20hacked%20on%20the%20user%20network.%0A%0AAs%20per%20the%20report%20put%20together%20by%20the%20AdvIntel%20security%20experts%2C%20over%2010%20Cobalt%20Strike%20beacon%20sessions%20were%20installed%20in%20the%20early%20phases%20of%20the%20cyberattack.%0A%0AThe%20infection%20followed%20a%20typical%20attack%20flow%20wherein%20the%20adversaries%20gained%20access%20from%20the%20compromised%20VPN%20log%20by%20installing%20a%20crypted%20form%20of%20Cobalt%20Strike%20inside%20the%20Costa%20Rica%20sub-network.%0A%0AAfter%20gaining%20local%20network%20domain%20administrator%20access%2C%20the%20threat%20actor%20utilized%20the%20Nltest%20command-line%20tool%20to%20enumerate%20domain%20trust%20relationships.%0A%0ASource%0A%0AThe%20cyber%20intelligence%20firm%20provides%20detailed%20information%20on%20the%20ransomware%20gang%E2%80%99s%20activity%20on%20the%20Costa%20Rica%20government%20network%2C%20including%20the%20specific%20commands%20used%20at%20each%20stage.%0A%0AConti%20scanning%20the%20network%20of%20Costa%20Rica%20govt%0A%0ASource%0A%0AThe%20experts%20said%20that%20the%20fileshare%20output%20was%20then%20downloaded%20to%20a%20local%20device%20by%20MemberX%20using%20the%20Cobalt%20Strike%20backdoor%20channel.%20The%20hacker%20gained%20access%20to%20administrative%20shares%2C%20where%20they%20uploaded%20a%20Cobalt%20Strike%20DLL%20beacon%20and%20used%20the%20remote%20file%20execution%20tool%20PsExec%20to%20run%20it.%0A%0AThe%20researchers%20also%20state%20that%20Conti%20developers%20used%20the%20open-source%2C%20credential-dumping%20application%20Mimikatz%20to%20carry%20out%20a%20DCSync%20and%20Zerologon%20attack%20that%20granted%20them%20access%20to%20all%20the%20hosts%20on%20Costa%20Rica%E2%80%99s%20interconnected%20networks.%0A%0AIn%20order%20to%20ensure%20that%20they%20wouldn%E2%80%99t%20lose%20access%20in%20the%20event%20that%20security%20specialists%20find%20the%20Cobalt%20Strike%20beacons%2C%20the%20attacker%20installed%20the%20Atera%20remote%20access%20tool%20on%20machines%20with%20less%20user%20activity%20where%20they%20had%20administrator%20rights.%0A%0AThe%20adversaries%20pinged%20the%20whole%20network%20and%20re-scanned%20the%20network%20domain%20trusts%2C%20leveraging%20enterprise%20administrator%20credentials%20with%20ShareFinder%20and%20compiling%20a%20list%20of%20all%20corporate%20assets%20and%20databases%20available%20under%20their%20new%20elevated%20privileges.%0A%0ASource%0A%0ADue%20to%20the%20use%20of%20the%20Rclone%20open%20source%2C%20multi-threaded%2C%20command%20line%20computer%20program%2C%20which%20can%20handle%20files%20on%20various%20cloud%20storage%20services%2C%20data%20theft%20was%20possible.%20This%20was%20used%20by%20the%20Conti%20ransomware%20gang%20to%20upload%20files%20to%20the%20MEGA%20file%20hosting%20service.%0A%0ABye%2C%20Bye%2C%20Conti!%0AA%20note%20on%20the%20Conti%20leak%20website%20suggests%20that%20the%20initial%20ransom%20demand%20was%20%2410%20million%2C%20but%20when%20Costa%20Rica%20declared%20that%20it%20was%20not%20paying%20it%2C%20it%20was%20raised%20to%20%2420%20million.%20Nevertheless%2C%20according%20to%20AdvIntel%2C%20messages%20between%20Conti%20members%20revealed%20that%20the%20price%20was%20significantly%20lower%20than%20%241%20million.%0A%0AIn%20response%20to%20attacks%20by%20the%20Conti%20ransomware%20organization%20on%20numerous%20government%20bodies%2C%20Costa%20Rican%20President%20Rodrigo%20Chaves%20declared%20a%20national%20emergency%20on%20May%208th.%20Some%20of%20the%20impacted%20institutions%20restarted%20activity%20in%20early%20June.%0A%0AAbout%20a%20week%20later%2C%20the%20creators%20of%20Conti%20ransomware%20began%20to%20wind%20down%20the%20business%20by%20taking%20some%20of%20the%20infrastructure%20offline%20and%20declaring%20that%20the%20brand%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20exist%20anymore.%0A%0AEverything%20came%20to%20an%20end%20at%20the%20end%20of%20June%20when%20the%20ransomware%20gang%20decided%20to%20take%20down%20the%20data%20leak%20site%20and%20all%20the%20websites%20used%20to%20negotiate%20ransoms%20with%20victims.%0A%0AIf%20you%20liked%20this%20article%2C%20follow%20us%20on%20LinkedIn%2C%20Twitter%2C%20Facebook%2C%20Youtube%2C%20and%20Instagram%20for%20more%20cybersecurity%20news%20and%20topics.&model=en_core_web_sm&pattern=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A2%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LOWER%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22Conti%22%7D%5D%7D%5D)

My idea is from the text in the URL (malware news), label correctly the word "conti", however when I try it using SPacy matcher, it recognize "Costa rica", "one", "attack" and other words as "Conti"!

Why is this? Can somebody clarify it? How should I do it to just label "conti" word?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I dont know how the official matcher explorer works but i did some tests with pycharm and it is matching correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).